# Custom action bar / header for Android

Tags: android, header, android-actionbar, customization

I'm trying to create a custom header but i've no clue about how to do it. I've been researching but i always have problems with styles and stuff that my eclipse won't have. 
The thing is that i want something very simple.

The screen in Android 4.2.2 would be something like this:

http://imageshack.us/a/img838/8840/89ur.png

I think this is the default header of Android SDK 11 and so on. I've been testing it changing the manifest android:targetSdkVersion and the look of my phone app changes.

The problem is the compatibility between different Android versions. I've seen the app working in different devices and this was the result:

In Android 4.0.4

http://imageshack.us/a/img600/6246/rdhl.png

In Android 2.3.6

http://imageshack.us/a/img836/1599/ezit.png

You can notice how is the Header and even colors and shapes change. 
If i create a custom header, will it be seen the same way in every device or it will depend on the Android version?

I'd like to make an only version of the app for every device, is it possible?
If it's possible, i'd like the next header of the first picture, and, inside the red rectange i'd like to insert an Image. If i can keep the options menu (yellow square) there, better. If it's not possible due to Android version, there is no problem to be activated with the hardware button.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: In that case, I would go for a custom action bar implemented as a linear layout in an XML file and including it with <include> tag.

Comment: @DídacPérez and how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not practical and probably not recommended, but what I do is I hide the actionbar/head altogether in the Android Manifest using:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".My_Activity_Name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" />
```

Then, inside my activity's layout xml file, I simply custom build a header which looks like actionbar/header. Here's an example in one of my apps:

[image]

That is completely done in the xml file, but it looks as real as the proper actionbar/header.

**EDIT**

This is my xml layout for the navbar:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:background="@drawable/navbar_topxml"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/nav_back"
            android:onClick="nav_back" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.99"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tab_style"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="TITLE"
            android:textColor="#888888"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center" >
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/todo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/todo_off"
                android:onClick="todo_toggle" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center" >
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/favourite"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/fav_off"
                android:onClick="fav_toggle" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center" >
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/done"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/done_off"
                android:onClick="done_toggle" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a reply for the n4h1n' question in the comment.

layout_action_bar.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="46dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="5" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageSearch"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/search" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="6" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textColor="#FF9C00"
            android:text="@string/turipolis" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="5" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageUser"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/user" />

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/action_bar_shadow" />
```

And in your activity XML:

```
<include
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    layout="@layout/layout_action_bar" />
```

Comment: in which part of my activity should i include the <include>? I'm getting the image of the header but not in the right position

Comment: In my case, my whole activity is a vertical horizontal layout, so I put the include as the first element of the layout.

Answer (score 1):

I would seriously recommend ActionBarSherlock, http://actionbarsherlock.com/. It really is an awesome library. You can find some of its code demos here http://actionbarsherlock.com/download.html, and their source code here https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/tree/master/actionbarsherlock-samples

However I do remember google announcing that they've backported the ActionBar to 2.1 in their support libraries here http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html. In activities that you plan to use it instead of extending the normal Activity class, you will be extending ActionBarActivity class. The same logic somewhat applies to ActionBarSherlock, in that you'll be extending SherlockActivity

Comment: That's right, lots of developers use that ActionBarSherlock, but, as Adam says: 'Added ActionBar to allow implementation of the action bar user interface design pattern back to Android 2.1 (API level 7) and higher. Use of this class requires that you implement your activity by extending the new ActionBarActivity class.'

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is just set a theme with no Title bar in your manifest and include in your XML file a custom layout file which is your titlebar. That makes sure that it is in every version the same. The benefits of it is that you can make everything of it.

Comment: And how can i do that? i've seen something like that and i tried it but the title bar won't appear. If i set this layout with my tittle bar, the options menu will dissapear and i wont be able to include it in Android versions where the options button is in the bar. Do you know any page where i can find a tutorial of this you were talking about?

Comment: See my answer below... It shows how to hide the TitleBar in the manifest.  Then in the activity's Layout xml file, you build your custom title bar.